# Insert takes effect before commit

Tags: mysql

I wrote the code bellow and even though I don't reach to commit (I deliberately put different usernames) since there is an error the first insert takes effect. Is there anything that I have not understood about transactions?

```
START TRANSACTION;
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;
INSERT INTO user(username,password,name,bdate,address,mail,htel,mtel,role) VALUES ('user1' , 'mypassword' , 'name' ,'yyyy-mm-dd' , 'address' , 'myemail' , '2106026838' , '6985963773' , 'student'); 
INSERT INTO student(student_username,year,studentsectorid) VALUES ('user2','5','2' );
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Try to use `SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;` before `START TRANSACTION;`.

Comment: Go through this [MySQL document](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mysql/5771/transaction/20368/start-transaction#t=201612261644274177005)

Comment: Are your tables `InnoDB` or `MyISAM`? `MyISAM` aren't ACID compliant, you can't use transactions with them.

Comment: No they are InnoDB. As far as I understand the rollback should happen withount even adding the " SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0; "

Comment: How do you execute this script? Is it run in mysql console client?

Comment: Yes, in MySQL workbench.